# Wordpress Can't seem to return archive of costum-post-type

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

This has been driving me crazy all day, not sure what I'm doing wrong, but perhaps one of your sharp eyes will catch it...

Basically, I have posts from a custom post type ('eac_english') that I want to archive. Using WP Template hierarchy guidelines, creating a doc called 'archive-eac_english.php' should take care of this, but when I add my code to this doc, it doesn't call the defined posts. It instead just returns a blank page.

Here's my funtion.php code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'eac_english',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'English' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'English' )
            ),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'en'),
        )
    );
```

And then, in a doc labelled archive-eac_english.php I have the following:

```
<?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'eac_english',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'category_name' => 'past-featured-artist', //name of category by slug
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 12)); // how many posts to show
    $x = 0;

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="home_post_box">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('grid-image'); ?></a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="home_post_text"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div><!--//home_post_box-->  

    <?php $x++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have an  'eac_english" post with with the category defined as 'past-featuerd-artist', but when I visit that page 'url/category/past-featured-artist/' nothing is returned.

Now if I take all the code in 'archive-eac_english.php' and add it to 'archive.php' it works no problem, but obviously that doesn't give me the option to only call the post organized under 'eac_english'.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!
cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Just realized I called the archive page 'archive-eac_english' I changed this to 'category-past-featured-artist' and all worked out.